# Running out of memory in Docker inside a Virtual Machine

Tags: docker, memory

I am running Docker on an Oracle virtual machine (VM), and running a Drupal instance, where I do migrations from version 7 to version 8 database, both of which are there. The migrations were running fine but lately I am getting a memory error. Looking at the VM settings, I have plenty of memory, however.

This is the error:

```
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error. [error] Error: Allowed memory size of 404750336 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 199233536 bytes) in /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php, line 686
```

Comment: How much memory does your virtual machine have?

Comment: When i click on the settings of the Oracle VM virtual box manger , under system it says 4MB

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code is trying to allocate more memory than is allowed in `php.ini`. You will need to increase the [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/memory-limit) setting.